# How to determine whether a given time in a given time zone is DST or not in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dst, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm using postgresql. And I want to determine whether a given time is in DST or not in postgresql by `SQL` or `SQL` functions created by `CREATE FUNCTION` statements.

For example. In time zone `Europe/Rome`, local time from `2017-03-26 03:00:00` to `2017-10-29 02:59:59` is in DST.

- If the given time is `2017-04-01 00:00:00`, then the result should be true.
- If the given time is `2017-11-01 00:00:00`, then the result should be false.

How to use SQL to realize the function in postgresql?
Is there any transition table that stores the transition time points, like the results of `zdump -v Europe/Rome` command in linux? Or is there any internal function can do this?

Looking up tables is always slow. Searching for a fast way.

Answer (score 1):

I assume smth like:

```
t=# create or replace function dst(t timestamp, tz text) returns boolean as
$$
declare
begin
  return (select t at time zone 'UTC' - t at time zone tz = utc_offset from pg_timezone_names where name = tz);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# select dst('2017-04-01 00:00:00','Europe/Rome');
 dst
-----
 t
(1 row)

t=# select dst('2017-11-01 00:00:00','Europe/Rome');
 dst
-----
 f
(1 row)
```

I left plpgsql instead of sql for additional logic, eg, checking `pg_timezone_names.is_std` or so. if not needed - change to SQL will be faster

Comment: Thanks for help.

Is there any faster way to solve the problem? Looking up a table is always slow.